# Failed to get high quality image: Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: java, android, android-studio, camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to capture Image using camera Intent and send it to server.

I have followed the official doc https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

But getting exception while using FileProvider to get the Uri from the filepath.

I am getting an exception

ERROR -
*Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.capture/files/Pictures/20200703_162914_2747394966410567504.jpg*

filepaths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="my_images" path="."/>
</paths>
```

CODE-JAVA

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName =  timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.d("mylog", "Exception while creating file: " + ex.toString());
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Log.d("mylog", photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    }
```

Manifest

```
<application>
...
...
...
  <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepath" />
        </provider>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FileProvider` path should point to the location where you file resides.

Change this in `filepaths.xml`:

```xml
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <cache-path name="my_images" path="."/>
</paths>
```

To this:

```xml
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <external-files-path name="Pictures" path="Android/data/com.example.capture/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Comment: No. As getExternalFilesDir() askes for `<external-files-path `.

Comment: @blackapps you are right, I've edited my answer. Look at the path that he is passing, it points to his applications directory.

Comment: Repeat: getExternalFilesDir() askes for <external-files-path. No need to edit a post as it makes a comment not valid.